# I cannot understand why it work like that

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, operator-precedence

```
x = 2
y = 2
if x % 2 == 1 & y % 2 == 0:
    print(x, y)
```

```
2 2
```

I don't understand the result.
When there is `if x % 2 == 1 & y % 2 == 0:`, I think `2 2` cannot be there.

Comment: One thing to note is that `&` has higher precedence than `==`. I believe you did not consider that.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean to use `&&` instead of `and`? `&` means bitwise AND, `&&` is condition chaining.

Comment: @MadsHougesen `&&` doesn't exist in Python, you probably mean `and`.

Comment: Please post your full code, clearly explain what is happening and what should be happening, and ask a question. You forgot thr question part.

Comment: `&` is a bit operator, for logical and you need to use `and`

Answer (score 1):

Let us demystify:

`%` has higher precedence than `&`

`&` has higher precedence than `==`

So the order of execution will be `%`, `&`, `==`

```
x = 2
y = 2
if x % 2 == 1 & y % 2 == 0:        # x%2, y%2 will be 0 
    print(x, y)
```

Will become:

```
if 0 == 1 & 0 == 0:                # 1 & 0 will be 0
    print(x, y)
```

Will become:

```
if 0 == 0 == 0:
    print(x, y)
```

Will become :

```
if True:
    print(x, y)
```

Output

```
2 2
```

**A snapshot of precedence table:**

[image]

[precedence](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/precedence-and-associativity-of-operators-in-python/)

Answer (score 0):

The *if-statement* is executing the following.

```py
(x % 2) == 1 & (y % 2) == 0
```